# Oracle optimizer is not accepting index hint

Tags: performance, oracle, plsql, query-optimization

When I run the merge query then index cannot read and query is running very slow please advise me.

Index in stage_dim_accounts(rbc_code)

Index in map_rbc_etl(free_code_9)

```
MERGE INTO stage_dim_accounts t 
USING map_rbc_etl s ON (t.rbc_code = s.free_code_9)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
SET t.indx_no= s.indx_no  
WHERE s.annexure= 'AXN-I' 
AND (.free_code_9 <> 'NA' AND s.free_code_9   <> '0') 
AND t.rbc_code <> 'NA'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `explain plan` say?

Comment: Please review your post.  The columns you list in the indexes do not matched the columns in the code (they're switched).

Comment: Are any of `MAP_RBC_ETL.ANNEXURE`, `MAP_RBC_ETL.FREE_CODE_9`, or `STAGE_DIM_ACCOUNTS.RBC_CODE` nullable?  If so, which ones are nullable and which are not?

Answer (score 3):

The optimizer is smart enough to know that your indexes are useless.

An index on `free_code` might be useful if most of the values in that column were either '0' or 'NA'.  As you haven't provided any information regarding data volumes or distribution we can't tell.  But you have other restriction criteria on  `map_rbc_etl`, so the database needs to go to the table anyway.  My guess is that optimizer has chosen to use a full table scan on map_rbc_etl because that's quicker than a huge number of indexed reads.

This is because an indexed read is two operations - read the index, read the row.  So it only pays dividends if the *percentage* of rows read is tiny.  Otherwise it is just more efficient to read all the rows and winnow them in memory.

Here is the great "secret" of tuning: indexed reads are not always faster; full table scans are not always bad.

Similar logic applies to reading the `stage_dim_accounts`.  The indexed column is unlikely to be selective.  Unless ... unless the number of rows in  `map_rbc_etl` is very small and only matches a small selection of rows in  `stage_dim_accounts`.  My previous comment on data metrics applies again.

Answer (score 0):

indexes to use
on map_rbc_etl( free_code_9, annexure)
and on stage_dim_accounts(rbc_code);

now these may not be used for reasons in previous answer.
Additional reasons an index may not be used are:
1. The optimizer decides it would be more efficient not to use index.
2. if column is on view and has function call on column.  To use this use function based indexes. 
3. you perform mathematical operation in query.  Note you can look at explain plan and create index to match how it is loading the rows.
4. you concat columns together in where clause.  Use function based index for overcoming this.
5. You do not include first column in concatenated index in where clause of your statement.  Note that Oracle 9i or greater do skip scanning and can use the index.
6. You use or clause.  In this case it is best to create one index for all but the or clause and one for each of the or values then it will use all indexes appropriately.

if you don't know how to use function based indexes an example for a to_upper() in where clause you would use the following

```
create indexName on tableName(to_upper(colname));
```

any oracle sql function (built in or user created) can be in the index.